# MySQLi query does not execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

While executing this code snippet

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM 'teklab_support' WHERE 'archive' = 0 and 'adate' < 'mdate'");
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
echo $row_cnt;
```

I don't get any Output or Error.

The Query is definetly correct - tested in PHPMyAdmin.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you check you web servers logs? Whats the value of  $result. If you run the finished sql in your db management do you get any rows?

Comment: You are confused with the usage of single quotes.  I consider this a typographical error.

Comment: No way this is query works via phpmyadmin.  There are lots of syntax errors

Comment: Single quotes for string literals, not table or column names.... if you want to quote those, then  use backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we actually found the solution

`$count = $db->sql_numrows($db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM 'teklab_support' WHERE 'archive' = '0' and adate < mdate"));
echo $count;`

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't look very well setup

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'teklab_support' WHERE 'archive' = 0 and 'adate' < 'mdate'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($results);
echo $row_count;
```

Comment: doesn't work as well.

I found I have to use something like this:

`$result = $db->sql_fetchrow($db->sql_query("SELECT ...");
$result['fieldname'];`

Comment: This is the same code in an even more awkward form. This doesn't fix any of the serious problems in the query either. `$result->num_rows` is the correct way to do it.